# How to pause a for loop until DispatcherTimer has ended?

Tags: c#, wpf, for-loop, mvvm, timer

I want the for loop to wait until the timer has finished, and afterwards continue the for loop. How do i need to do this? I tried with await & async, i am doing something wrong.
What it does now: the loop starts, runs the timer but does not wait for it to finish. So it loops on, and starts up the timer again.

More over my project: It is a motor tester for motorised beds. This piece of code needs to run for the time that the motor is moving up or down.
Herefore i'm using MVVM, WPF, ADRUINO UNO.

If someone has a good suggestion, i would love to hear.
(sorry for my bad english).

> PIECE OF CODE:

```
private async void Loop(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DOORLOOPTEST.Properties.Settings.Default.LOOPS; i++)
        {
            string value = DOORLOOPTEST.Properties.Settings.Default.UP_or_DOWN;
            switch (value)
            {
                case "UP":
                    _time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(HeadUpTime);
                    _MotorMove = new Task(() => MotorMove(sender, e, _time));
                    await _MotorMove;
                    break;

                case "DOWN":
                    _time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(HeadDownTime);
                    _MotorMove = new Task(() => MotorMove(sender, e, _time));
                    await _MotorMove;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void MotorMove(object sender, EventArgs e, TimeSpan _time)
    {
        TimerBegins(sender, e);
        LOOP_timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
        {
            if (_time == TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                LOOP_timer.Stop();
                LOOP_timer.Tick += TimerIsGedaan;
            }
            _time = _time.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
        }, Application.Current.Dispatcher);

        LOOP_timer.Start();
    }
```

Comment: You haven't provided code for `TimerBegins` and `TimerIsGedaan`, but seemingly all you want is a non-UI blocking delay for `_time` timespan? In which case you could just make `MotorMove` async, and replace the `DispatcherTimer` with a single await `Task.Delay(_time)`? Or am I missing something? Also, it looks like `TimerIsGedaan` is only subscribed once the timer stops - is that expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify the comments:

Unless there is more to the code than your MVCE, seemingly the only purpose of `DispatcherTimer` is to introduce a delay of `TimeSpan _time`, ticked off in quanta of 1 second, and where the final tick then Stops the timer, subscribes `TimerIsGedaan`, and then starts the timer again?

Assuming that all you want to do is invoke `TimerIsGedaan` once `TimeSpan _time` has elapsed, how about converting `MotorMove` to async, and using `Task.Delay`

```
private async Task MotorMove(object sender, EventArgs e, TimeSpan _time)
{
    TimerBegins(sender, e);
    await Task.Delay(_time);
    TimerIsGedaan();
}
```

Unless you need a new thread each time, you could also consider removing the `Task.Run` from your `Loop` code, i.e.

```
 await MotorMove(sender, e, _time);
```